# How to insert char* into map<string,string>?

Tags: c++, string, dictionary, char

I have 2 words that taken as `char*` , I want insert them to `map<string,string>` , thus I tried 2 ways and they didn't work -

1st way  -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
void main()
{
    map<string,string> myMap ; 
    char cWord[4] = "abc"; 
    char cValue[4] = "123";
    myMap.insert(cWord,cValue) ; 
}
```

I got an error  -

```
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_tree.h: In member function ‘void std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_insert_unique(_II, _II) [with _InputIterator = char*, _Key = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, _Val = std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, _KeyOfValue = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, _Compare = std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_map.h:553:   instantiated from ‘void std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(_InputIterator, _InputIterator) [with _InputIterator = char*, _Key = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, _Tp = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, _Compare = std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >]’
testString.cpp:10:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_tree.h:1324: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::_Rb_tree<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >::_M_insert_unique_(std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, char&)’
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_tree.h:1206: note: candidates are: std::_Rb_tree_iterator<_Val> std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_insert_unique_(std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<_Val>, const _Val&) [with _Key = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, _Val = std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, _KeyOfValue = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, _Compare = std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >]
```

2nd  way -

```
    // same include's as above ..
    map<string,string> myMap ; 
    // char* init ..    
    char cWord[4] = "abc"; 
    char cValue[4] = "123";

    // string ..
    string word(cWord) ; 
    string value(cValue) ; 
    myMap.insert(word,value) ;
```

I got an error -

```
error: ‘::main’ must return ‘int’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.4/map:60,
                 from testString2.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_tree.h: In member function ‘void std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_insert_unique(_II, _II) [with _InputIterator = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, _Key = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, _Val = std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, _KeyOfValue = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, _Compare = std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_map.h:553:   instantiated from ‘void std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(_InputIterator, _InputIterator) [with _InputIterator = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, _Key = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, _Tp = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, _Compare = std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >]’
testString2.cpp:15:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_tree.h:1323: error: no match for ‘operator++’ in ‘++__first’
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_map.h:553:   instantiated from ‘void std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(_InputIterator, _InputIterator) [with _InputIterator = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, _Key = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, _Tp = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, _Compare = std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >]’
testString2.cpp:15:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_tree.h:1324: error: no match for ‘operator*’ in ‘*__first’
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
void main() //first mistake, it should be int main()
{
    map<string,string> myMap ; 
    char cWord[4] = "abc"; 
    char cValue[4] = "123";
    myMap.insert(cWord,cValue) ; //third mistake, char * != string.
    //and return 0;
}
```

Rectification:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    map<string,string> myMap ; 
    string cWord = "abc", cValue = "123";
    myMap[cWord] = cValue ;
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

As you can see from the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/insert/)<sup>1</sup>, the `map.insert` overload that you need takes a single parameter. There it's not immediately evident, but it wants a `pair<string, string>`, containing the key and the value. You can do, for example:

```
myMap.insert(make_pair(string(cWord),string(cValue)));
```

which converts the `char[]` to `string` "on the fly", creates the `pair` with them and inserts it in the map; you cannot do `make_pair(cWord, cValue)` because there's not an implicit conversion from `pair<char *, char *>` to `pair<string, string>`;

Still, in this case it's way easier to just use the `operator[]`<sup>2</sup>:

```
myMap[cWord]=cValue;
```

Notice that here you can avoid the construction of the `string` temporaries, because in this context the compiler is allowed to create them automatically.

By the way, it's `int main`, not `void main`.

---

1. [Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) is more precise and up to date with the C++11 additions, but IMHO less clear for a novice.
2. But keep in mind that the semantic of `insert` and `operator[]` is different when the key already exists: `operator[]` overwrites, while `insert` does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Like so:

```
myMap[cWord] = cValue;
```

Alternatively, with a pair:

```
myMap.insert(std::pair<std::string const, std::string>(cWord, cValue));
```

Or with `emplace`:

```
myMap.emplace(cWord, cValue);
```

You should use the `[]`-accessor if you want to set the mapped value unconditionally, and the `emplace`/`insert` functions if you want control over the situation where the key already exists.